# How to get preview when sharing your websites specific page (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, dynamic-routing

I have hosted a website. When I share the link of the website I am getting the preview of it. But when I am sharing a particular page of the website like https://example.ai/pagename I am not getting the preview of it. I am using react-router-dom browserRouter.
[This is what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp1AP.jpg)
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I need more information to help, you deployed it where? maybe code sample.

Comment: I deployed it in aws. The website is working fine. I just want the link preview to appear while sharing the pages.